# How to make regular array table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

[image]

I have been unable to find a satisfactory solution to creating the aforementioned table array.

I think this is a simple and interesting problem for senior developers, but it is difficult for me. I hope to be able to solve it soon.
Really sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What pattern are you supposed to use to create the table?

Comment: What partial solutions have you found and tried? Are you looking to output an html table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer:

```
let num_arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let inner_arr = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    inner_arr.push(i * i + j * j + 4 * i * j + j + 1);
  }
  num_arr.push(inner_arr)
}

console.log(num_arr)
```

I'm not sure if the solution I found is the most optimal.
I figured out this formula with pen and paper.

Based on your purpose, you can modify the values of `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but what you're trying to do is to create a 2D array, so effectively an array of arrays:

```
let arrayOfArrays = [
    [1, 3, 7, 13],
    [2, 8, 16, 26],
    [5, 15, 27 ,41],
    [10, 24, 40, 58]
];

console.log(arrayOfArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
function create2dArray(rows,columns) {
  var x = new Array(rows);
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    x[i] = new Array(columns);
  }
  return x;
}
```

to generate the array and then you can fill accordingly with your values.

```
var myArray = create2dArray(4,4);
```

will create a 4x4 array and you can fill it accordingly with your values having in mind that myArray[0][0] is the to left box.

As per the image you can assign the values:

```
myArray[0][0] = 1;
myArray[0][1] = 3;
...
```